# ¿Cómo clonar instancias de objeto en Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Teniendo el siguiente código, como se puede clonar la constante `a` que a su vez tiene una propiedad con instancia de la clase `CA`:

```
import lodash from 'lodash';
class CA {
  public p = "dato de P"; 
  constructor() {}
  public getP(){return this.p;}  
  public getP_arrow = ()=>{return this.p}
}
const a = {
  ca : new CA(),
}
//Alternativas usadas:
const clon_json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
const clon_str =  structuredClone(a);
const clon_lodash = lodash.cloneDeep(a); //⚠ preferiria no libreria externa
//Ejecucion:
console.log(clon_json.ca.getP()); //❌Error (se perdió la referencia)
console.log(clon_str.ca.getP()); //❌Error (supuestamente getP no es una función)
console.log(clon_lodash.ca.getP()); //✅ funciona pero...
clon_lodash.ca.p = "Nuevo dato";
console.log(clon_lodash.ca.getP_arrow()); //"dato de P" , ❌ no lo clonó
```

¿existe una manera optima de clonar un objeto en Typescript (incluso en Javascript)?

Comment: Entonces la pregunta no se corresponde con el título. Ya que ya descubriste varias formas de hacerlo y en realidad preguntas por la **mejor** forma.

Comment: Hola amigo, no, precisamente intente varias formas pero ninguna garantiza una completa clonación, ahí esta el problema

Comment: Las funciones [no son clonables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#things_that_dont_work_with_structured_clone) y eso incluye los métodos de una clase. Ignoro qué hace el reemplazo de Lodash, pero por lo visto pega esos métodos estáticamente y se pierde el estado de la instancia ca

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces un `stringify` se genera un JSON a partir de la estructura del objeto, pero si observas bien en esa esa estructura no van las funciones

```js
class CA {
  constructor() {this.p="dato de P"}
  getP(){return this.p;}  
}
const a = {
  ca : new CA(),
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Entonces cuando vuelves a convertir a objeto usando `JSON.parse` pierdes el tipado, en consecuencia el objeto resultando ya no es del tipo `{ca:new CA()}`

Lo mismo pasa con `structuredClone` que en la [documentación del algoritmo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#things_that_dont_work_with_structured_clone) lo especifica claramente

> Function objects cannot be duplicated by the structured clone
> algorithm; attempting to throws a exception.DataCloneError

---

*Edit 24/07/23*

Según tus comentarios, entiendo que lo que necesitas es una "clonación profunda". Para esto puedes crear una función `clon` que:

- Evalue si el objeto en cuestion es un `Object` anonimo o si tiene constructor. En caso que lo tenga, instancear un nuevo objeto de ese tipo.
- Luego recorrer las propiedades para setearlas al nuevo "objeto clon" y en caso de que la propiedad sea del tipo `object` repetir la función `clon`

```js
class CA {
  constructor() {this.p="dato de P"}
  getP(){return this.p;}  
  
}
const a = {
  ca : new CA("a"),
}

Object.prototype.clon = function(){
   const new_obj = typeof this.constructor !== "function" 
   ? {} : new this.constructor();
   
   for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this)) {
     if( typeof value === "object" ){
        new_obj[key] = value.clon();
     }
     else{
        new_obj[key] = value;
     }
   }
   return new_obj;
}

a.ca.p="más datos de P";
const clon = a.clon();
clon.ca.p="clon P";
console.log(a.ca.getP());
console.log(clon.ca.getP());
```

La función anterior es sencilla y quizás requiera afinarla para otros casos de uso, pero esa es la idea general.

El tema principal aquí, es tu quieres hacer algo que Javascript no lo permite. Sencillamente no es posible hacer clonación al nivel que (entiendo) tu estas sugiriendo, porque no todos los objetos son [serializables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy), esto lo explicita la documentación:

> ...muchos objetos JavaScript no son serializables en absoluto...

Esto no es exclusivo de Javascript, en `C#` por ejemplo no puedes deserializar a una clase que no tenga un constructor si argumentos. Con el código de ejemplo que te he puesto pasa algo similar, por ejemplo:

Esto aun funciona:

```
class CA {
  constructor(p) {this.p=p}
  getP(){return this.p;}  
}
const a = {
  ca : new CA("un dato"),
}
```

Pero de la siguiente manera arroja una excepción:

```
class CA {
  constructor(p) 
  {
    p(); //aquí faltaría una validación if(p)
  }
  getP(){return this.p;}  
}
const a = {
  ca : new CA(a => console.log("imprime")),
}
```

**¿Por qué?**

Porque el truco está en ir instanciando un nuevo objeto y copiar sus propiedades (entendiendo que sus propiedades representan el "estado" del objeto), por este motivo es necesario que el `constructor()` pueda ser ejecutado sin argumentos que arrojen error. Ya que evidentemente puede haber casos que no conocemos el argumento original

Seguramente (y lo digo con poca seguridad) una clonación real requiera de un manejo de memoria que javascript no tiene.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero no es la solución, analizando tu código creo que el problema estuvo en que intentaste dar solución a este código en específico y no una solución general, analiza lo siguiente, mira en los 2 ejemplos que propusiste, ¿Cuántas veces instancias la clase `CA`?  (2 veces) en si no es clonación, tu código se resume casi a hacer:  `const a = { ca : new CA()};   clon_a = {ca = new CA()}` con la diferencia que estas clonado las propiedades literales que tenga la constante `a` pero no la propiedad `ac` que lo que hace es crea una nueva instancia de esta.

Comment: También lo puedes comprobar si asumimos lo siguiente:  justo antes de ejecutar la clonación ( así como la sugieres:`Object.assign(structuredClone(a),{ca:new CA()}); ` )  ejecutáramos una modificación como `a.ca.p = “más datos de P”`, esta modificación no se vería reflejada en el clon (a pesar de ser ejecutada antes de la clonación) por  que `clon.ca` es una nueva y diferente instancia.

Comment: @MagnerLesmes Toda la razón, he editado mi respuesta para responder a tus comentarios. Saludos